# PHP Redirect to different URLs based on Parameters

Tags: php

I'm currently using this simple redirect (which passes all URL parameters to the next page) to redirect a link:

```
    <?php
        function preserve_qs() {
        if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?") === false) {
            return "";
        }
        return "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://example.com/" . preserve_qs());
    ?>
```

One of the issues is that I have with this method is that I need to create a separate file for each redirect.

Is it possible to make this into something that I simply add different URLs inside and based on URL parameter that I call, it sends people to the right URL.

For example, in PHP, we store 3 URLs and we assign them 3 values (parameters):

```
example1.com = page1
example2.com = page2
example3.com = page3
```

and the PHP file URL would look like this:

`example.com/redirect.php?land=page1?restofparameters`

keep in mind that the rest of the parameters need to be sent to the goal page, but not the page1 parameter which calls the URL inside the PHP file.

So the target URL that people will land will would look like this:

example1.com/?restofparamaters

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try .htaccess method... like this...

**In *.htaccess* file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(1)? http://triviamaker.com [R=301,L]
```

then for check this one

localhost/**your_project_folder**/test/1

Note:- that **.htaccess** file must be in Root directory of your Project.

& if you have any query or found any problem related to that **.htaccess** method then you can Search "redirect a specific url to another url with htaccess" in Google. you will Found more details easily about this...

hope this one is Helps to you... Thank You...

Comment: Thanks but it needs to be php, won’t work like this.

Comment: I write another solution below, please check out & try

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a link parser.

But here goes an example based on your code for stripping and inheriting GET URL parameters.

```
<?php
  function preserve_qs() {
    if (empty($_GET)) return '';
    return '?'.http_build_query(array_diff($_GET, ['land']));
  }

  http_response_code(301);
  header('Location: https://example.com/' . preserve_qs());
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: thanks but that still doesn't have multiple URLs to redirect to. I was thinking of using an array but not sure how it would play out.

Comment: So what you are missing is a switch or a bunch of conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I write this in test.php  ... just for your Reference

Run This File for check Output...

http://localhost/url_rewrite/test?2
and run also like this http://localhost/url_rewrite/test?land=2

```
echo $temp = $_GET['land'];
echo $temp = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($temp == "1" || $temp == "land=1"){
        header('Location: https://example.com');
    }else if($temp == "2" || $temp == "land=2"){
        header('Location: https://gmail.com');
    }else if($temp == "3" || $temp == "land=3"){
        header('Location: https://apple.com');
    }else if($temp == "4" || $temp == "land=4"){
        header('Location: user/2');
    }
```

I hope this helps to you... Thank you

Comment: Thank you! This works almost perfectly, the only issue is that it doesn't pass the query string after land and it shows a text when anything is added after.

Comment: Basically "land" pulls the url, and passes any other query strings add after, such as "pid" for example.